# CodeIgniter 4: Two controller name shown in URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm new to this, and I was wondering why my controller appears twice on my URL. So I have a navbar, and when I click a menu, the URL looks like `http://localhost/Home/index`, but when I click another menu, the URL changes to `http://localhost/Home/Home/stud_admit` and shows the `404 - File Not Found`, `Controller method is not found: Home`.

Routes.php

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);

$route['(:any)'] = "Home/$1";
$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->get('/', 'Home::stud_admit');
```

Home.php - Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;
use AppControllersBaseController;

class Home extends BaseController
{

  public function index() {
    $data = [];
    $data['title']   = 'SMS';
    $data['heading']    = 'Welcome to SMS';
    $data['main_content']   = 'home';   // page name
    echo view('innerpages/template', $data);
  }

    public function stud_admit()
    {
      $data = [];
      $data['title']        = 'SMS | ADMIT STUDENT';
      $data['heading']  = 'Welcome to SMS';
      $data['main_content'] = 'stud-admit'; // page name
      echo view('innerpages/template', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: and its working fine ?

Comment: @AqibJaved nope. It shows the `404 - File Not Found Controller method is not found: Home`

Comment: @cjwrk please show us your *navbar/menu* source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have auto routing turned on, simply remove from your routes file:

`$route['(:any)'] = "Home/$1"; $routes->get('/', 'Home::index'); $routes->get('/', 'Home::stud_admit');`

You don't need them.

Comment: The result is still the same even if I removed them.

Comment: I don't know what happened but it works now. Thank you!